# Change bootloader (remove Grub) with dual boot Windows 10/Linux Mint 17

Tags: windows-10, grub, easybcd

I have a laptop that runs Linux Mint 17 and Windows 10- that is to say Windows 7 "upgraded" to Windows 10 such that the bootloader shows Windows 7, instead of Windows 10.

I want to uninstall Linux Mint from my laptop, mainly to free up space because I no longer need it, but I think that the bootloader (`grub`) might interfere and make things bad. `EasyBCD` shows no option for Windows 10.

What's the way to change the bootloader now?

Comment: Boot to a Windows 10 installation disk and use the utility to repair the Windows bootloader, which is the same command, across all current versions.

Answer (score 1):

"Automatic Repair" option of [Dual-boot Repair tool for Windows 10](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) (and earlier Windows versions) will write proper boot files so Windows 10 will boot by default.

Then you can safely delete Linux Mint partitions using Disk Management or another disk utility.

For renaming loader entry you can use bcdedit.exe or [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net). Change text of Description element of loader.